# Diseño de alineamiento de texto e iconos en botones con css

Tags: css, css3

Necesito ayuda en lo que dice, estoy diseñando estos botones, pero no se ven con un orden, les adjunto la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno lo que deseo es algo asi (como ven en la imagen todo esta ordenado)

**Texto a la derecha e iconos a la izqueirda**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y bueno esto es mi css.

```
page-home {
    p {
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
    }
    .body {
        background-color: #FFEB3B;
    }
    .botones {
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 17px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Bueno el HTML es en ionic:

```
<ion-content padding class="body" align="center">
    <img src="../../assets/logo.png" class="imagen">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='logo-facebook'></ion-icon>
        Registrate via Facebook
      </button>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="secondary" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='person-add'></ion-icon>
        Servicio Particular
      </button>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="dark" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='briefcase'></ion-icon>
        Servicio Corporativo
      </button>
    <br>
    <p>¿Eres nuevo? <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">REGISTRATE AHORA</a></p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el html para tener una mejor idea de lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Es en hmtl en ionic, igual ya lo agrege

Comment: yo lo veo ordenado, cuando dices ordenado exactamente dondo quieres ubicar que cosa o simplemente quieres copiar el diseño...

Comment: primero que nada los iconos esta ala izquierda y sin margen y me parece que el texto esta tambien alineado a la izquierda pero conun margen de X %

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez gracias por comentar, bueno texto a la derecha e iconos a la izquierda como esta en la iamgen inferior

Comment: tendrias que verificar primero que CSS afecta el icono y cual al texto del boton. y agregar clases custom para cada una...

Comment: En eso necesito ayuda :c

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores hay te deje un par de ejemplos abajo.

Answer (score 1):

creo que para el icono tendrías que agregar las clases, algo como:

```
icon-left
icon-right
pull-right
pull-left
```

pero para el texto del botón tendría que ser algo custom:

html:

```
<button ion-button item-end round full icon-start class="botones text-custom-botones">
```

css:

```
.text-custom-botones{
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  #padding-right: 30px !important;
}
```

y creo que puedes meter 30% para que se adapte al diseño automáticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a dejar un posible ejemplo que se podría personalizar fácilmente, utilizo la librería [`fontawesome`](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) y el selector [`:before`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp).

*Ejemplo `FontAwesome`:*

```css
/* Posición boton */

button.fb,
button.part,
button.corp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .5s;
}


/* Posicionamos el icono fijo (selector :before). */

button.fb:before,
button.part:before,
button.corp:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem; 
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px; 
}


/* Añadimos iconones mediante css y fontawsome */

button.fb:before {
  content: "\f230";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

button.part:before {
  content: "\f234";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

button.corp:before {
  content: "\f0b1";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}


/* Personalizamos colores botones */

button.fb {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

button.part {
  background-color: Gold;
}

button.corp {
  background-color: Gainsboro;
}


/* Efecto hover */

button.fb:hover {
  background-color: LightBlue;
}

button.part:hover {
  background-color: Khaki;
}

button.corp:hover {
  background-color: DarkGray;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- FontAwsome Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="fb">Registrate via Facebook</button>
  <button class="part">Servicio Particular</button>
  <button class="corp">Servicio Corporativo</button>
</body>
```

Ahora si deseas utilizar la `liberia IONIC`, hay que modificar pequeños valores.

> Un motivo porque personalmente me gusta más `FontAwesome`, cuando abres desde su web un icono, te muestra el *Unicode* de ese icono, por ejemplo, Unicode: `f2c4`, no lo he visto en `IONIC`, personalmente no lo he utilizado, pero lo he tenido que buscar en el `CSS`.

*Ejemplo `IONIC`:*

```css
/* Posición boton */

button.fb,
button.part,
button.corp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .5s;
}


/* Posicionamos el icono fijo (selector :before). */

button.fb:before,
button.part:before,
button.corp:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Añadimos iconones mediante css y fontawsome */

button.fb:before {
  content: "\f231";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
}

button.part:before {
  content: "\f480";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
}

button.corp:before {
  content: "\f110";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
}


/* Personalizamos colores botones */

button.fb {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

button.part {
  background-color: Gold;
}

button.corp {
  background-color: Gainsboro;
}


/* Efecto hover */

button.fb:hover {
  background-color: LightBlue;
}

button.part:hover {
  background-color: Khaki;
}

button.corp:hover {
  background-color: DarkGray;
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- IONIC LINK HTTPS CORREGIDO -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="fb">Registrate via Facebook</button>
  <button class="part">Servicio Particular</button>
  <button class="corp">Servicio Corporativo</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Faltaria alinear el texto, debe estar a la izquierda del icono pero alineados a la derecha ...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez he actualizado el código, simplemente al botón principal le he añadido un `text-align: right;` y `padding-right: 1rem;`, espero que es así como te gusta, saludos.

Comment: algo es algo pero la idea era otra si vez el original tanto los iconos como el texto estan alineados a la izquierda, pero el texto tiene un pading como de 40 px para separarlo del icono

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez ahora te entendí, mira mi ejemplo ahora, a ver si la tercera es la vencida.

Comment: si ahora si eso es lo que quiere el men de la pregunta saludos, aunque el lo queria usando el recurso de IONIC, no Fontawesone.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez te he dejo un ejemplo aparte con la librería `IONIC`, la que usas, ya me comentas a ver si te ha solucionado tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: no funciona creo

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez En el fragmento funciona correctamente, algo estarás haciendo mal. Saludos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63571/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-francisco-nunez).

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez si visitas la pagina oficial, veras que esta en `http` y no en `https`, te dejo su web para que lo observes tu mismo, http://ionicons.com/, y si quieres evitar futuros problemas en tu código te aconsejo ponerlos de esta manera: `//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css`

Comment: no es por la pagina original es por las restricciones que existe en el protocolo y la reglas de cross-origin... algo basico.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline" slot="end" >
  </ion-icon>
```

Comment: Hola Ricardo, aunque el código compartido puede servir para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace ese código? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? ¿dónde iría dentro del código de la pregunta? Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.

Comment: Hola por favor modifica esta publicación en base a lo que comenta Alvaro, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por aquí dejo mi aportación:

Dentro de la etiqueta button coloca un span que será el icono en cuestión y a este span añádele un float right.

Al texto de la etiqueta button añádele un text-align left.

Fijate en el ejemplo práctico de abajo.....

(En los ejemplos se está utilizando fontawesome).

```css
.my-button {
   width: 200px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   text-align: left;
   display: block;
}


.icon-pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Iconos a la derecha</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  
</head>

<body>
  
      <h3>Ejemplo 1</h3>

      <button class="my-button" type="button">Item01 <span class="icon-pull-right fas fa-caret-right"></span></button>

      <button class="my-button" type="button">Item02 <span class="icon-pull-right fas fa-caret-right"></span></button>

      <button class="my-button" type="button">Item03 <span class="icon-pull-right fas fa-caret-right"></span></button>

      <h3>Ejemplo 2</h3>

      <button class="my-button" type="button">Item01 <span class="icon-pull-right fab fa-facebook-square"></span></button>

      <button class="my-button" type="button">Item02 <span class="icon-pull-right fab fa-twitter-square"></span></button>

      <button class="my-button" type="button">Item03 <span class="icon-pull-right fab fa-linkedin"></span></button>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos @FernandoBonilla, tu respuesta quedaría mucho más completa si agregas una explicación sobre como funciona y como resuelve el problema de OP, recuerda que hay usuarios que apenas van comenzando y no comprenderás el código. ;)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A ver ahora qué tal....